# execute python commands from the xml spreadsheet

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7

I have a xml spread sheet with test name, procedure and arguments.
I am able to parse it having dummy data in a python dict as:

```
{
    'TC#1': ['Connect to node1', "tl1.sendCmd(10.110.45.74,9090,userId=secadmin,password=admin)"],
    'TC#2': ['Connect to node2', "tl1.sendCmd(10.110.45.74,userId=secadmin,password=admin,dummy='testData')"],
    'TC#3': ['Connect to node4', "tl1.sendCmd(10.110.45.74,userId=secadmin,password=admin,dummy='testData')"],
    'TC#4': ['Connect to node4', "tl1.sendCmd('',userId=secadmin,password='')"],
    'TC#5': ['Connect to node4' ,"tl1.sendCmd(10.110.45.74,userId=secadmin,password='')"],
    'TC#6': ['DisConnect to node4', "tl1.sendCmd('10.110.45.74')"]
}
```

What could be the better way to execute these set of tests. With all import statements and setup data. Going forward I am planning that I can put the python code directly in place of test procedure.

Kindly provide the possible approaches. It's a kind of keyword driven framework part